# Why is cargo recompiling for every change

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

Recently I noticed that with every change I make to my project, `cargo build` recompiles a good chunk of dependencies. I ran the build with the verbose option and I see that it is caused by `x11-dl` which uses `pkg-config`.

```
Dirty x11-dl v2.21.0: the env variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH changed
Compiling x11-dl v2.21.0
```

```
2023-11-28T16:00:29.568162Z DEBUG cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint: new local fingerprints deps "/home/m2johnson/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/x11-dl-2.21.0"
2023-11-28T16:00:29.568527Z DEBUG cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint: write fingerprint (59a258ee54e4dd64) : /home/m2johnson/project/target/debug/.fingerprint/x11-dl-63f654e4528e2978/run-build-script-build-script-build
     Running `/home/m2johnson/.rustup/toolchains/1.73.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name x11_dl --edition=2021 /home/m2johnson/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/x11-dl-2.21.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=309 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C debug-assertions=on -C metadata=a622a30e33ea17c3 -C extra-filename=-a622a30e33ea17c3 --out-dir /home/m2johnson/project/target/debug/deps -C linker=clang -L dependency=/home/m2johnson/project/target/debug/deps --extern libc=/home/m2johnson/project/target/debug/deps/liblibc-eaa316218c225a80.rmeta --extern once_cell=/home/m2johnson/project/target/debug/deps/libonce_cell-d50086842dfc3ee6.rmeta --cap-lints allow -C link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld -l dl`
```

What I've tried:

- I saved a file in the project with no changes and it seems to give the same "Dirty" warning with the same fingerprint calculated.
- I checked my `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in the terminal and with a `build.rs` file and they were identical.
- I closed `vscode` and ran entirely from the terminal. This *did* seem to stop the recompile. I guess this means that either `vscode` (`rust-analyser`) is modifying `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` or that it isn't reading the value when its started (i.e. clearing it).

So, how does the change detection work? I've traced it back to [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/2d1c64bbc756b3115b41bd8f10de79dd16d6a539/src/cargo/core/compiler/fingerprint/mod.rs#L999C44-L999C44) so far but no luck yet in understanding whats going on.

This is with Rust 1.73.0

```
rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE that could be compiling your code with a different environment set?

Comment: Probably this library has miss-configured build script and runs it every time.

Comment: I was right. If you look at its [build.rs](https://github.com/AltF02/x11-rs/blob/master/x11-dl/build.rs) file you can see that there are no `rerun-if-changed` directives, which will result in running build script every time. You should either fork this library and add it yourself, or try to merge such patch to the upstream.

Comment: @kmdreko I'm using vscode. I was running the build from the terminal but it was still open. Closing everything, it seems like this stops the recompile so I guess vscode is running the build with a different environment? That's annoying.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I believe that library outsources the env directives to [pkg-config-rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/pkg-config-rs/blob/ef638e8a6c6bb2d077abe952421f5f262f14d49c/src/lib.rs#L470C29-L470C49) which does add the right directives.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I think it's the opposite? If there aren't directives, the code never recompiles.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I think you are right. [Cargo reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#life-cycle-of-a-build-script) states that "By default, Cargo will re-run the build script if any of the files in the package changes." Which will result in constant re-running of a build script in a "final" crate, but since the dependency doesn't change it should not rerun it.

Comment: @Michael you can try following this answer to a cargo FAQ [Why is cargo rebuilding my code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/faq.html#why-is-cargo-rebuilding-my-code).

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I have, the output is in the original question. ("Dirty..." is with `--verbose` and the "DEBUG" lines are with the extra logging).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with lots of dependencies being needlessly recompiled. For me, it was fixed when I disabled rust-analyzer in vscode, but this is not ideal.

A better solution for me was running the task `rust: cargo run` from the command menu (the same as clicking the run button above the main fn).
This solved the issue.

You can also create a shortcut for this:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+[Backslash] r",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "rust: cargo run"
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work for your situation.